# How can I make my Python script run after 2 hours?

Tags: python, datetime, subprocess

I wrote a program that will close the hard drive with BitLocker in Windows by using libraries `datetime` and `subprocess` but I cannot get the correct result.

---

**Here is my code:**

```
import subprocess
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today()
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
time_delta = now + delta
# print(time_delta)
# print(now)
try:
    if now == time_delta:
        close = subprocess.check_output(['manage-bde', '-lock', 'D:', '-ForceDismount'])
        close.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
        print('done')
except Exception:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are checking the current time `now = datetime.datetime.today()`, then add 2 hours to it and immediately after check, if `time_delta` is equal to `now`.

Thus the if statement always results in false and the code in it does not get executed.

You need to put something in place to wait. Something like that.

```
import subprocess
import datetime
import time
now = datetime.datetime.today()
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
time_delta = now + delta

while now != time_delta: 
    time.sleep(1) # wait for a second
    now = datetime.datetime.today()
# when now == time_delta we continue here:
try:
    close = subprocess.check_output(['manage-bde', '-lock', 'D:', '-ForceDismount'])
    close.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    print('done')
except Exception:
    pass
```

This is not the best way to schedule a task, but it should be working.